# using android.support.v4 library in Intellij idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, adb

In my android project I tryed to use `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

Before it I added it to the `libs` library (`cp MySdkForder/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar MyProjectFolder/libs`)

After that I added it to the `classpath` like this:

[image: my project settings]

So I have a code like this in my `main.xml` file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This one I took somewhere on `developer.android.com`

Idea renders this code totally fine

[image: how idea renders this code]

Problems starts when I'm trying to launch it. When I press `run` I have the following error from `adb`

```
Cannot reload AVD list: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing /usr/lib/android/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing /usr/lib/android/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/devices.xml
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing /usr/lib/android/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing /usr/lib/android/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/devices.xm
```

It looks like this

[image: Error message]

The funny thing is that I can't even close it (It appears again and again). But that's not my question. The question is how to make this `android.support.v4` work? As I think I've done everything what I needed (added this library to `libs` and made dependencies) and `adb` still doesn't want to work (It works absolutely fine If I don't use `android.support.v4`, just standard features)

Comment: What do your build.gradle files look like?

Comment: @MichaelA. Actually I'm a total newbie, so I don't even know what it is and dont use it. When I started this project I just selected `Android -> Application Module`, not `Gradle: Android Module`. Do you think using it can solve my problem?

Comment: Android Studio uses gradle as its build system anyway. The build.gradle files are auto-generated by the GUI (though it is often useful to edit them manually). You should have at least two - one in the root directory of the project, and one in each module directory. I recommend getting to know them, though in this case, it is probably not your problem.

Comment: @MichaelA. I dont know if it's crutial but I'm using Intellij Idea instead of Android Studio (though it's pretty the same thing, as I understand). I tryed to build it from Android Studio. It still falls with errors but doesn't show this demon alert

Comment: Just noted this. Yes.

Comment: Definitely this is a show-stopper for Intellij.

Comment: I had same problem. Just deleted the virtual devices in the AVD and remade them.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I am using Genymotion and I don't need android wear images. I did following:

1. Uninstalled using SDK manager:

   a) Android 5.1.1 (API 22) -> Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image

   b) Android 5.1.1 (API 22) -> Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image
2. Removed all devices using AVD manager and create new one.

Works for me.

Comment: Thanx for a nice solution. But this is not necessarily android 5.1.1, it was 6.0 for me.

Comment: Should have known better than to just install the entire 6X folder. +1

Comment: My problem came when I installed 6.0, as my previous versions did not have those things checked probably because they did not exist so the upgrade of adding 6.0 broke things.  Removing 6.0 made things work like they had.  Now I am adding part of 6.0 back but leaving out the android wear.  Thanks for this answer.  Quickly solved what seemed like a difficult problem.

Comment: I just deleted Wear images, and the problem gone

Answer (score 12):

I just had this problem go here: `usr/lib/android/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-22`

And remove the android wear folder.

Answer (score 7):

Solution For android Studio.
Open sdk manager

delete Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image and Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image packet.
 @gosha is told true.works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Error Solution:-

1. Uninstall Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image.
2. Uninstall Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image.

Restart Android Studio...and enjoy!!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Delete these 2 packages using Android SDK Manager.

1. ARM EABI v7a System Image
2. Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image

View the image link here for more clarification.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq2tK.png

Answer (score 1):

Use text editor to open Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
Search 280dpi
Change it to hdpi

Do the same for Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

Close eclipse. Restart eclipse. The error should disappear.

If you are working with windows, the files could be in 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

Comment: This did not help. The only change is that now it's `280hdpi` in the error instead of `280dpi`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, I suspect the problem is the setup of your Android Virtual Device, rather than anything with the project.

Have you tried running the project on an actual Android Device including the support library? If that works, there is not problem with your project setup.

If the problem is the AVD, as surmised, you need to go into your AVD manager and take a look at what the setup of your devices look like. I don't use VDs a lot myself, but one potential issue is that you may be missing the Google APIs in your setup.

Edit:

Just noted your clarification about using IntelliJ. It sounds like your project/IDE setup of the AVD has some issues. It is probably possible to hunt down and figure out the what has gone wrong by doing diffs on a working Android Studio project, but you'd probably save yourself a lot of time and effort by simply installing and using Android Studio. It's not very different, but there are enough Android-specific features in Studio that I think it is worth it even if it means you have two or more IDEs installed.

Comment: I did not try because I can't run it. Every time I click `run` this error occures and I can't close it. Without `android.support.v4` it runs perfectly on my device. And I dont know any other ways to run my application on phone except clicking `run`

Comment: The error message you've posted implies that you are trying to run this on an AVD. Connect your actual Android device with a USB cable, run "adb devices" in a terminal to verify that it is connected, and go into "Run >> Edit Configurations", find "Target Device" and either set it to "Show chooser dialog" (uncheck use same device...) or set it to USB device.

Comment: Note, you should have side-loading (install of non Google-Play store apps) and USB debugging enabled on the Android device you use as well.

Comment: My device is connected and USB debugging mode is enabled. "Target device" is set to "Show chooser dialog" and every time I click `run` it opens, but this error occures over it. So I can't choose anything. Moreother as I find out now, this error occures even when I just click `Run >> Edit Configurations` as you avised so I can't even edit it.

Comment: I tryed my best and clicked very fast to close an error and choose my device. Yes, it works on my phone though this neverending error still occures

Comment: That sounds weird - it might be worth reinstalling your Android Studio, because I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be doing that. But if it works correctly on your actual device, you definitely need to take a look at your VD setup ("Tools >> Android >> Android Device Monitor" or start it up externally).

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is the version of android being used by idea in it's android plug-in which is installed under `plugins/android/lib/`.

I can see that this should be addressed in IDEA 15 as that will use a later version of android in the plug-in. That version has an entry for `280dpi` in it's *devices-2.xsd* that is packaged in the *sdk-tools.jar*.

I tried to hack the entry into the current *devices-2.xsd* but that causes the plug-in to completely fail later on. *So don't try do do that!*

If you aren't doing wear development, then the answers saying to remove those directories from the platform image are valid.

You can also *live* with the problem by positioning the annoying error dialogue so that it's ok button is over which ever element you are trying to click in *Choose Device* dialogue beneath it. Then double click. Tedious, but you do get there.

Comment: Actually I would go against the suggestion to live with it (the double-click trick). In my attempts, there was a huge possibility that the 2nd click will only let the OK button on Choose Device gain focus (the button itself highlighted) instead of actually starting my device. Eventually all windows in Android Studio got frozen (Error dialog not working since the UI focus was held by Choose Device's OK, and the Choose Device dialog got masked by Error dialog), and I had no choice but to kill them all through Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

we can see the error:   we can get the info, this error is about sdk/system-iamges/android-22/android-wear iamge.

So we can delete the sdk/system-iamges/android-22/android-wear  directory. it works for me!