# Android Studio wont work, first app

Tags: android

I am just starting out learning Android (Java) in Android studio but I have hit a wall, whatever I try I cant get it to work.

Every time I start a new project (for example myFirstApp) and try and run it i get the error message

> "Cannot reload AVD list  cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not
>   facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi,
>   xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the
>   enumeration. Error parsing
>   C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.**"

When I try and run the app on the emulator I get an error due to this message, I have looked around google and I cant find any answers that help me, It is driving me insane.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to make an Android Wear app?

Comment: When you start a new project, select only Mobile device and ignore other devices like android TV and Android auto, or wears.

Answer (score 0):

they discussed it here before: [Android : Getting "Cannot reload AVD list:" error at the time of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645126/android-getting-cannot-reload-avd-list-error-at-the-time-of-execution)

Apparently deleting the android wear folder should help.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have decided to reinstall everything from scratch, I got rid of the android wear folder and it didn't work... I will update with any info I get when I install again (and a few lower SDK's)