# RE: Error running android project

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I've updated my SDK from ver 22 to 24 along with the build.
Also , i've changed the project structure complied sdk and build version to 24.

When i try to run my project, I get the following error:

> Cannot reload AVD list: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not
>   facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi,
>   xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the
>   enumeration. Error parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
>   560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
>   parsing
>   C:\Users\111299\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xm

Please advise .

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253381/using-android-support-v4-library-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you make the `devices.xml` file or was it auto-generated?
2) What other resources are you using? Hav you defined multiple layouts for different screen sizes? Do you have imported bitmaps and other image or related files?

**I suggest you check your drawable and mipmap folders.** The error code specifically indicates "system-images", "ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi" etc.

Comment: I just installed Android studio fresh and downloaded the required stuff from SDK manager.

Comment: Should I create a new project ? Please advise.

Comment: First, try to import your old project into the freshly downloaded Android Studio. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest manually migrating over your code. I think if you search a bit on the net you may be able to get a better suggestion as to what to do next. Also, if you're satisfied by the answer, mark it as accepted :D